# How to resolve async error in javascript method call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following async javascript code which calls the async method `findDevices` of the class `Devices`, in another file. It's an async method since I'm doing a mongo find in collection `IDevices` within that method. The code is below:

```
let devices = await Devices.findDevices()
```

The class is below:

```
module.exports = class Devices{
    static async findDevices() {
            let devices = await IDevices.find({"Region" : {"$exists": false}})
            loggingService.getDefaultLogger().info("Devices without region: " + devices)
            return devices
        }
}
```

When I try to execute this code, I get the following error:

```
let devices = await Devices.findDevices()
              ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error since findDevices is an async method. How can I resolve this error and how should I be calling this method. Is there another approach I'm not considering and don't I need the method to be asyn since I'm doing a mongo find with mongo collection `IDevices`?

Would wrapping it in an async function look like this:

```
async function regionBackfill() {
    let devices = await Devices.findDevices()
    if(devices){
        devices.forEach(device => {
            await Device.updateRegion(device.SerialNumber)
        });
    }
}
```

If so, would I just call `regionBackfill()` ? How would I call it? If I just call it as: `regionBackfill();` I get the same error

Comment: await is only valid in async function. Is your statement `let devices = await Devices.findDevices()` in an async function. That is the rule. Wrap it in an asyn func and call it or use then.

Comment: The error is in `let devices = await Devices.findDevices()`, not `let devices = await IDevices.find({"Region" : {"$exists": false}})`.

Comment: @TusharShahi, I've updated my question. How can I wrap it in an async function and then call it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Comment: forEach will not respect await inside it. regionBackfill() is causing an error. Don't call it with await. If you are doing that then we are back to the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

async await is basically syntactic sugar over promises.

The way to use async function is:

```
const example = async () => {
  await otherCall();
}
```

Also you can do:

```
async function example() {
  await otherCall();
}
```

For your specific question, I've one suggestion to make calls parallel:

```
async function regionBackfill() {
    let devices = await Devices.findDevices()
    if(devices){
        Promise.all([...devices.map({SerialNumber} => Device.updateRegion(SerialNumber)])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you tryed call the method without a async method. You may call the method thus:

```
Devices.findDevices().then(response => devices)
```